# Warning in assigning packed structure to global structure

Tags: c, initialization, arm, variable-assignment, packed

I'm running on an (embedded) ARM architecture.

I have a structure `Brown`:

```
typedef struct
{
    float A;
    float B;
    float C;
}Brown;
```

a packed structure `Abo` that contains `Brown`:

```
#pragma pack(2)
typedef struct
{
    Brown Left;
    Brown Right;
}Abo;

Abo AboSent;
```

A global variable:

```
Brown Dest;
```

now I want to assign `AboSent.Left` to the global variable `Dest` (that is not packed):

```
Dest = AboSent.Left;
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
use of address of unaligned structure member
```

Now when I use a local variable in the middle it compiles fine without the warning:

```
Brown Test = AboSent.Left;
Dest = Test;
```

Why is that? How the local variable in the middle made the difference?

I know that this warning happens when passing unaligned pointer, but here it is not a pointer.

Comment: So the question boils down to why `Brown Dest; Dest = AboSent.Left;` issues a warning while `Brown Dest = AboSent.Left;` doesn't. From which we again nicely see that "*assignment*" and "*initialisation*" are not the same.

Comment: But they are both assignments, done in the same function in my code, line after line.

Comment: `Brown Test = AboSent.Left;` isn't an assignment, but an initialisation.

Comment: I understand now, thanks a lot!